# wp_schedule_event not working

Tags: php, wordpress, scheduled-tasks

I am making a program that checks and send email in an hour using `wp_schedule_event` but it won't work on my end.. does any one have an idea about my case? this is my code I put it on my custom plugin `myplugin-function.php`

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
}

function do_this_hourly() {
    $headers = "From: webmaster <webmaster@test.com>\r\n";

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    mail('mymail@test.com','Test','Hello',$headers);

}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');

function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code seems to be taken out of the WP doc, I would think it's more a config issue than a code's problem.

Maybe these steps should help you:

1. Check that `WP_DEBUG` in your `wp-config.php` file is set to `true`
2. Check that `DISABLE_WP_CRON` is not present, or at least not setted as `true` in your `wp-config.php` file
3. Try to check if your event is scheduled `$schedule = wp_get_schedule( 'my_hourly_event' );`, and you dump `schedule`
4. If you can have access to your server logs, take a look if there is errors about the `wp_cron.php` file
5. Take a look at the [ALTERNATE_WP_CRON](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Alternative_Cron) option docs, it may helps you, but I don't really like this solution

I know that I don't give you any answer but we don't have a lot of information (as you don't).

Hope it's gonna help you.