# Wordpress wp_schedule_event() Not Triggering

Tags: wordpress

I have a function contained within a custom plugin that I am trying to trigger on a daily basis, using wp_schedule_event(). However, no matter what I try, I can't get it to work!

First, I tried using this code (which works well on another Wordpress site using a custom plugin that triggers a function hourly, but does NOT work on this site)

```
/** Set Recurring Hourly Event for Function Execution */

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'bt_events_activation');

function bt_events_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'btpg_hourly_event');

}

add_action('btpg_hourly_event', 'doThisFunction');


/** Clear Recurring Hourly Event for Function Execution when plugin is deactivated */

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'bt_events_deactivation');

function bt_events_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('btpg_hourly_event');
}
```

Then I tried using this code from another Stack Overflow question here
[wp_schedule_event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132835/wp-schedule-event-not-working)
But it doesn't work either.

```
/** Set Recurring Hourly Event for Function Execution */

/* Add FB Sync schedule */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cp_fb_schedule');

// Scheduled Action Hook
function cp_fb_scheduled_sync_function( ) {
doThisFunction();
}

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function cp_fb_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync' );
    }
}
add_action( 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync', 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync_function' );

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'tpg_deactivation');
```

Am I missing something really simple? Is there a server setting or wp-config.php setting that needs to be updated? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your great answers and suggestions!

It turns out my problem was that I was editing the code directly from the command line and was not "deactivating" and "reactivating" the plugin after my changes!

I finally realized that in order to implement my changes to the code, I had to "deactivate" and then "reactivate" the plugin in order to reset the Wordpress scheduled event.